# How to compare a class return with a float or integer?

Tags: python, class, integer, compare

I want to compare the `__repr__` of a class with a float or an integer.

```
class TestClass:   
    def __init__(self, a = 5): 
        self.a = a     
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.a
```

This obviously returns an error, because `a` is not a `string`:

```
TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type int)
```

If I set it as a string, the print is correct:

```
>>> TestClass()
5
```

but the print is not comparable:

```
>>> TestClass() == 5
False
```

What should I use to compare the class return to make it `TestClass() == 5` to `True`?

Comment: Maybe do `TestClass() == "5"`? Comparing two strings this way. Or, IMO better, `int(TestClass()) == 5`

Answer (score 5):

Neither.

`__repr__` is only called in cases where you need a string and get an object, *such as from `print` or as a single expression on the command line*, and is meant as a *human-readable* representation of an object that it (hopefully) can be reconstructed from.

Recall that without overloading `__repr__`, what you get from the command line is a string denoting the *identity*, as opposed to the *value*, of an object, e.g.:

```
<__main__.TestClass at 0x20feb8836d8>
```

On the other hand, what you are doing with `TestClass() == 5` is a *value* comparison.

Therefore, it would only evaluate to `True` if you defined `__eq__`, the equality method:

```
class TestClass:   
    def __init__(self, a = 5): 
        self.a = a    

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other

print(TestClass() == 5)
```

Output:

```
True
```